# How do I return/implement the toString for the ArrayList? Also, just want to check that I've correctly created my objects?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, tostring

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;

public class List2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Loan newLoan = new Loan();                  
        Date theDate = new java.util.Date();
        Circle newCircle = new Circle();
        String s = new String();
        //last semicolon is also an error?

        private ArrayList<Object> List = new ArrayList<Object>();

        List.add(newLoan);
        List.add(theDate);
        List.add(newCircle);
        List.add(s);

        //**There's an error underlining all my . and ; when I add them to the List above?

        public String toString() {
            String results = "";
            for (Object d : List) {
                results += "," + d.toString();
            }
        }
    }
//I'm pretty new to this stuff
```

Comment: Whats the question sorry?

Comment: and whats the error? also your toString method should return the result

Comment: Read about java naming conventions. Variable names start lowercase; and "list" a really pointless name for a list. Names should tell something about intent, they are not mere placeholders!

Comment: Main method is not closed? Is this the complete program?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Beyond that: if such simple things are already overburdening you: step back; do some learning; and forget to pull together a JavaFX UI application (in case that is what is your goal)

Comment: You're trying to define `toString()` __inside__ `main`. You can't define functions directly inside other functions in Java. Also you can't declare local variables as `private` .

Comment: No, this is not a complete program. It's a simple piece of practice code. GhostCat, I beg to differ, I think this question is helpful to other readers....seeing that I've spent all afternoon researching this and didn't find anything that explains it simply enough for beginners. I know I've got lots of mistakes, as I'm new to Java programming. Thank you to everyone who gave helpful comments, they're very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of error in your code :

**First**
Don't ever name your variables with Upper letter in beginning, java use camelCase

**Second**
Don't declare your variable with private public in your method.

```
private ArrayList<Object> List = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

**Third**
You can't declare a method inside another method you have to close the first when you finish:

```
public static void main(String args[]){//------Start
  ...
}//---End

public String toString(){//---Start
  ...
}//---End
```

**Forth**
When you want to call a method with paramettres you can pass them like this :

```
method(list);
```

**Fifth**
ArrayList already impliment toString so you don't need to create it again, you can use :

```
list.toString()
```

If you want to implement it again you can use :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    King newLoan = new King();
    Date theDate = new java.util.Date();
    Circle newCircle = new Circle();
    String s = new String();

    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();

    list.add(newLoan);

    list.add(theDate);

    list.add(newCircle);

    list.add(s);

    System.out.println(newLoan.toString(list));
}

public String toString(ArrayList<Object> list) {
    String results = "";
    for (Object d : list) {
        results += "," + d.toString();
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had no idea that ArrayList already implemented a toString.

Comment: Woops. Thought I'd selected it...must've double clicked. Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

firt thing first...

your code is not compiling since you are breaking the sintax rules...

this here:

```
private ArrayList<Object> List = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

can not be declared **private** since you are INSIDE a method, that is just invalid,

since **List** is used in an static context it must be declare Static too, or create an Object of the class **List2**

on the other hand

**toString** method **returns** a string object, you need to return something then, like **results** object I can infer.